# Getting corrupted. '.xls' file via external API call in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to write a groovy script for my Jenkins pipeline which calls an API that outputs a '.xls' file and store it in the workspace directory.
I used the pipeline syntax generator to generate a script for HttpRequest which is as shown below.

CODE:

`def response =  httpRequest customHeaders: [[maskValue: false,  name: 'Accept', value: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet']], outputFile: './abc.xls', url: 'http://xyz/', wrapAsMultipart: false`

The above-mentioned code is able to download the file at the required location, but the file data is corrupted.
I tried using the default content-type/Accept available in Jenkins and even tried custom headers, but none of them seem to be able to retrieve the correct '.xls' file data.

When trying to hit the API with PostMan using Accept: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' in the header, the file data is received in its correct format, the file is not corrupted.

Can anyone help me in figuring out what might be the exact issue here?

Comment: Try `httpRequest contentType: APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM, outputFile: './abc.xls', url: 'http://xyz/'`

Comment: I tried contentType: APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM but result is same.  Getting file with corrupted data

Comment: Does it work via CURL?

Comment: curl -o out.xls  -H @{"Accept" = "application/octet-stream"} 'http:/xyz'  this is the code i used tried with Conternt-Type as well still getting file with corrupted data

Comment: How do you determine that the file is corrupted? Can you post a hex dump of the beginning of the file?

Comment: Gitting following data in the file
0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOwADAP7/CQAGAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAA/v///wAAAAD+9SAG8AbwB0ACAARQBuAHQAcgB5AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFgAFAf//////////AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP7///8AAAAAAAAAAFcAbwByAGsAYgBvAG8AawAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASAAIB////////////////AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAAAPkvAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: This looks like base64 encoding. Try to pass additional header: `Content-Transfer-Encoding=BINARY`

Comment: curl.exe -o out.xls -H  @{"Accept" = "application/octet-stream"} -H @{"Content-Transfer-Encoding" = "BINARY"} 'http:/xyz'
I tried in this way but still the same result

Comment: Try to compare headers sent by PostMan and Curl using a sniffer or a website that outputs headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentType` sets the request format, while `acceptType` defines the response format. Try setting the `acceptType` as follows:

```
def response = httpRequest url: "https:/....", httpMode: 'POST', 
    contentType: 'APPLICATION_JSON', 
    requestBody: JsonOutput.toJson(bodyParameters),
    acceptType: 'APPLICATION_OCTETSTREAM',
    outputFile: "${REPORT_FILE_NAME_COMPLETE_PATH}"
```